# Variable in shell script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
until [ $i -gt 6 ]
do
    echo "Welcome $i times."
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

Why we use double () in i=$(( i+1 )),and
why if we change the program to

`i=$( i+1 )`

or

```
i++
```

or

```
$i=$i+1
```

, it is not correct?

Comment: I've moved this to stackoverflow as this is not a request for people to review your code.

Comment: You can also do `((i++))`, `((i += 1))` or `((i = i + 1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$( foo )` tries to execute `foo` as a command in a subshell and returns the result as a string. Since `i+1` is not a valid shell command, this does not work.

`$(( foo ))` evaluates `foo` as an arithmetic expression.

It's just two similar (but different) syntaxes that do different things.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/dblparens.html

> Similar to the let  command, the
>   ((...)) construct permits arithmetic
>   expansion and evaluation. In its
>   simplest form, a=$(( 5 + 3 )) would
>   set "a" to "5 + 3", or 8. However,
>   this double parentheses construct is
>   also a mechanism for allowing C-type
>   manipulation of variables in Bash.